# How to split data to many column

Tags: excel

I have a column content a lot of data in special format (5d 14h 37m, 10d 10h 16m )
  i need to separate this data to be in 3 column column foe days, column for Hours and last one for minutes

i need it by formula only

NOTE: i take the data from system , i don't know how its code working i just take it copy past to one Cell

Comment: is there always the three?

Comment: Is the data `5d 14h 37m`, and `10d 10h 16m` on a separate row? Or are they in the same cell?  What have you tried? You could split text to columns using a space delimiter...

Comment: if you mean the format of the the data yes it is always three (10d 10h 16m) , if you mean i want to separate it always in 3 columns

Comment: yes, the data is in the same cell , the way of using text to columns will never serve my idea at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data in A1 put this in B1 copy over 3 columns and down till you get blanks.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(1:1)-1)*99+1,99))," ",REPT(" ",99)),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*99+1,99))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your Great effort . i will keep it " Brilliant "

Comment: @AhmedRady if it worked for you please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.